# Simplest method to filter a PWM'ed sinusoid?

Tags: pwm, filter, sine, emi-filtering

I am using PWM to dim a bulb and was wondering how I could restore the chopped waveform to a sinusoid whose amplitude varies with the duty cycle.

The switching frequency is 25Khz and the line frequency is 50Hz using a 25V transformer for the supply. The bulb is rated at 100W

To be honest, i don't really know where to start.

Should i be looking for off the shelf filters? or would it be better to design a configuration from a few capacitor and inductors?

I have found an example of a filter being used for exactly my purpose, but there is no information in the paper about the design of the filter elements. 
[image]

Here is a simplified schematic of the circuit I am using. 
[image]

Comment: What power level minimum and maximum. How close to a sine wave should the filter be designed for.

Comment: What do you mean by maximum and minimum power? 
The bulb is rated for 100W.

I was hoping to get the output waveform as close to a sine wave as is possible, however i cant really say i know enough about the matter to have a good answer for that question. 

Thus far i have read [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5544536&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F5523765%2F5542000%2F05544536.pdf%3Farnumber%3D5544536) which used a filter for recovery of a sine wave from PWM.

Comment: I mean what I say. Will it always be a 100 watt bulb or might this change. It us important btw. The circuit you show won't give you a decent sinwave and neither, it seems, is it compatible with your description of feeding pwm to the bulb. Precisely what does your power stage look like?

Comment: My circuit is set up similarly to the picture above, two MOSFETS connected to the bulb in the same manner. The gates are driven from an isolated dc-dc converter. I can get a schematic made if required. 
I may change the bulb in the future, but for now i am sticking with 100W. 

I haven't proposed that the filter shown above would be a good solution, rather i was trying to give extra context to my position. 

I already stated that i am far from educated on this matter, hence my posting of a question in this forum.

Comment: I think a circuit would be a good idea because, for example, I don't clearly see where the 25 volt transformer fits in.

Comment: i have updated the post to include a schematic.

Comment: Your goal is very similar to that of "power factor correction", altough the typical use of power factor correction is PWM after a rectifier to get sinusodial power consumption. Reading about power factor solutions should give you ideas for your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Why not feed the lamp with DC?  The you can just use fairly common PSU arrangement with output filtering.

DC would subject the lamp to even less stress than sine wave AC.

What type of lamp is it?  Can you use a different type?

Comment: Thinking back, i believe my logic was that by using AC i could filter the output to reduce EMI. I would still require PWM of the high DC currents for my closed loop control - though i believed filtering of this to be less simplistic than AC. 

This is still a problem i need to resolve though other projects have stolen my focus. 

I will need to read my write-up again to clarify - thanks for the reply! 

I appreciate the help

Comment: I just checked again, i am controlling a 100W load at 24V so PWM of the load produces high current pulsations and resulting RFI/EMI emissions. 

I believe AC to be required to reduce the EMI emissions at the load, though filtering at this power/current level seems to be problematic (or i cant seem to find much help). 

Am i correct in believing as i do thus far?

Comment: Actually feeding the load with DC will reduce the EMI. Filtering the PWM to DC will be easier than filtering to AC.

Comment: I see, could you elaborate or point me to some sources to educate myself on the matter. 
I don't understand how chopping pulsed or straight DC with PWM would differ from AC for each respective 500ms period (UK) in regards to the EMI it produced. I would love to read something to clarify that for me. 

Also the filtering of the DC - if my load is purely resistive, then could i use a simple RC configuration (with my load being R) to filter the DC? 

Thanks for your assistance - this is invaluable for me. 
Honestly!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an LC low pass filter to feed the bulb. This would significantly reduce PWM artefacts to the bulb BUT, because the bulb is resistive there is little point unless the bulb is located down several metres of cable and the cable might be regarded as an EM emitter.

You could design several stages of LC filter and each stage would offer an improvement on sine wave fidelity.

Comment: I am seeking to use a low pass filter not only for EMI considerations, but also to ease the stress on my bulb filament caused by PWM switching. 

Could you make any suggestions as to where to start with an LC low pass filter? 

Could i possible use an off-the-shelf component to recover the sine wave?

Comment: You need to have the capacitor across the bulb and the inductor in series with the fets BUT you'll also need inductor flyback protection when the fets go open circuit. I believe you'll need what is called a snubber across the fets. But you should ask yourself that all these extra components are likely to receive as much stress as the bulb you believe you are trying to protect.

Comment: Well, i am trying to design my circuit so as to ensure a decent bulb life. 
I would rather have a little power inefficiency with a good bulb life span than have to change the bulb regularly.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding me. The components in the filter and snubber will likely receive as much stress as the bulb. I believe your mean time between failures could be higher withe the filter components added.

Comment: I see. 

What are the contributing factors to this? 
The level of power used? 

As the paper i linked above seems to have employed the filter pictured above with success.

Comment: Much larger values are needed to give the lamp anything like a sine wave. Bigger values can mean less reliability due to voltages on the cap and self heating of the inductor.